# Рамка градиента для бордер радиус, как реализовать?

Tags: html, css

Вемсто чёрной рамки помогите сделать градиент

```css
.button_reg:hover{
    width: 100px;
   height:30px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
   outline: 0 !important;
   color:#d2bef7;
   background: linear-gradient(to top right, #a135b5, #7537e7);
   border: 0 !important;
}

.button_reg{
    width: 100px;
   height:30px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
   outline: 0 !important;
   color:#c9b6c3;
   background: #2c3e50;
   border: 1px solid black; 
}
body{
  background: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_login_block">
<button class="button_reg">
fare
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Градиент рамки сверху вниз:

```css
.xx {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-top: 20px solid #3ACFD5;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #3a4ed5;                                             
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 20px 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMSAxIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIj48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imxlc3NoYXQtZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMzYWNmZDUiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzNhNGVkNSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2xlc3NoYXQtZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz48L3N2Zz4=),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -o-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="xx"></div>
```

Градиент рамки слева направо:

```css
.yy {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-left: 20px solid #3ACFD5;
  border-right: 20px solid #3a4ed5;                                             
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100% ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 20px;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 20px;
  background-size: 100% 20px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), -o-linear-gradient(left, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%), linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a4ed5 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="yy"></div>
```

Диагональный градиент рамки:

```css
.zz {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 50px auto;               
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.zz:before,
.zz:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.zz:before {
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100% ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 20px;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 20px;
  background-size: 100% 20px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(right, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), -o-linear-gradient(right, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), linear-gradient(to left, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
}
.zz:after {
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 20px 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-size: 20px 100%;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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),url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(to top, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), -o-linear-gradient(to top, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3acfd5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%), linear-gradient(to top, #3a4ed5 0%, #3a8ed5 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="zz"></div>
```

Задавать кнопке border градиент не получится, на нее нужно наложить один из градиентов, указанный выше, и подправленный под эту кнопку.

Comment: я не случайно указал бордер сайз, таких вариантов полно в интернете, а вот с скругленной рамкой...

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев А в чем проблема указать `border-radius: 50%` ? Я все изменил на ваш скругленный бордер кроме диагонали.